# Custom Templates Django Formwizard

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, django-formwizard

This may be obvious to some, but I cannot figure out how to over-ride `get_template_name` to provide a different template to the different steps of my `form wizard`. Here is what I have so far:

```
class StepOneForm(forms.Form):
    color = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES) 
    ...

class StepTwoForm(forms.Form):
    main_image = forms.ImageField()
    ...

class StepThreeForm(forms.Form):
    condition = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CONDITION)
    ...

class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        id = form_list[0].cleaned_data['id']
        try:
            thing = Thing.objects.get(pk=id)
            instance = thing
        except:
            thing = None
            instance = None
        if thing and thing.user != self.request.user:
            raise HttpResponseForbidden()
        if not thing:
            instance = Thing()
            for form in form_list:
                for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                    setattr(instance, field, value)
            instance.user = self.request.user
            instance.save()
        return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
                'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],})
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^create/$', login_required(CreateWizard.as_view([StepOneForm, StepTwoForm, StepThreeForm])), name='create_thing'),
```

I have read the Django docs and tried to use the method described there. In my forms.py:

```
FORMS = [("step_one", myapp.forms.StepOneForm),
         ("step_two", myapp.forms.StepTwoForm),
         ("step_three", myapp.forms.StepThreeForm)]

TEMPLATES = {"step_one": "myapp/step-one.html",
             "step_two": "myapp/step-two.html",
             "step_three": "myapp/step-three.html"}

class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]
        ...etc. ...
```

But this returns a `KeyError at u'0'`. How can I get my form wizard to display different templates for each step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps in django form wizard are as  `'0', '1', '2', ...` so you need to update your `TEMPLATES` dict as

```
TEMPLATES = {"0": "myapp/step-one.html",
             "1": "myapp/step-two.html",
             "2": "myapp/step-three.html"}
```

And then use it `get_template_names` as you have done:

```
class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]
```