# Custom Django FormWizard Steps with Templates

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, django-formwizard

This is my working FormWizard that I made by following [this](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sy50G-jVX8Y&t=1389s)

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'wizardApp/index.html')

class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "wizardApp/contact_form.html"
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        process_form_data(form_list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('../home')

def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

    print(form_data[0]['subject'])
    print(form_data[0]['info1'])
    print(form_data[0]['info2'])
    print(form_data[1]['sender'])
    print(form_data[1]['info1'])
    print(form_data[1]['info2'])
    print(form_data[2]['message'])
    print(form_data[2]['info1'])
    print(form_data[2]['info2'])

    return form_data
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from wizardApp import views

from wizardApp.forms import ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactForm3
from wizardApp.views import ContactWizard

app_name = 'wizardApp'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^home/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^contact/$', ContactWizard.as_view([ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactForm3])),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm1(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    info1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    info2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

class ContactForm2(forms.Form):
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    info1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    info2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

class ContactForm3(forms.Form):
    info1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    info2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

contact_form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        {{ wizard.form.media }}
    </head>
<body>

<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>

<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        {{ wizard.form }}
    {% endif %}
    </table>
    {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
    <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">first step</button>
    <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">prev step</button>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am having a lot of trouble understanding how customizing each step of the form works. There is very little help out there for this unfortunately. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972436/custom-templates-django-formwizard) post about creating multiple templates and that kind of helps, but my main disconnect is on how i create those templates and how they are implemented in each step.

In a normal form i can do something like this

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-left">
                {{form.first_name}}
                {{form.first_name.errors}}
              </div>
              <div class="form-right">
                {{form.last_name}}
                {{form.last_name.errors}}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              {{form.email}}
              {{form.email.errors}}
            </div>

            <div>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>

        </form>
```

How do i access each individual field? Where i can add in html and other bits to help with general styling? How should i go about making one of these for each steps? Should i basically be copy and pasting the html and everything into other "templates"? How do i call each template for each step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Hope you figured it out. For the sake of anyone who runs into this, this is how I solved this. I replaced `{{ wizard.form }}` with a `for` loop to manually render the inputs:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for field in wizard.form %}
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
            {{ field }}
            <span class="message">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">first step</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">prev step</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

You can create a template for each of your forms and then associate it to its corresponding form as described in the [docs](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#using-a-different-template-for-each-form) or if you want each form to use the same template, all you need to do is set your `template_name` attribute in your ContactWizard class:

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "contact_form.html"
```